# WPF Button - Method when pressed

Tags: wpf, button

I want to call a method when a button is in the mouse down state (IsPressed) and call another method when it is released.  I can't seem to figure out a simple way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a situation in which you can use bindings, set a OneWayToSource binding on the IsPressed property of the button. When the source property changes, execute your code.

This should work regardless of how the button is pressed.

Comment: data binding is a pretty huge topic, but you may be able to get started with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx. At the company where I work, we rarely directly manipulate or poll the state of GUI objects, preferring instead to rely on bindings.

Answer (score 1):

There are MouseDown and MouseUp events that you can handle to get a similar effect.  But that won't handle the keyboard (spacebar) case.  You'll have to do that with a KeyDown and KeyUp event.

Also be aware that a MouseDown event MAY not ever be followed by a MouseUp event, if the user moves the mouse after pressing down to a point where it is no longer over the button.  (You can capture the mouse in MouseDown to guarantee you get the MouseUp event, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.aspx) class in the System.Windows.Input namespace. There are [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown.aspx) and [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup.aspx) attached events available.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there is a better way then trying to intercept the mouse events.  Some sort of trigger on the IsPressed propert?

Besides, I'm fairly sure you can't get some of the mouse events on a button as it is being intercepted by the system.